# My app is invoking virtual method getDoubleArray on a null object reference

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bundle

The app I'm making is giving me a fatal exception on my bundle.getDoubleArray("key").
It says I'm invoking a null object reference on it.

My code in the second fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        rezultat=new double[3];
        bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        rezultat=bundle.getDoubleArray("key");
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second,container,false);

        setTextR1(v);
        setTextR2(v);
        setTextR3(v);

        return v;

    }
```

Code in the first fragment where I'm putting a double array in the bundle:

```
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ArrayList<ValAtt> mValAtts=new ArrayList<>();
                Baza baz=new Baza();
                mValAtts=baz.getVA();
                double fibLoss, fibLen, lossBud;
                spinner=(Spinner) spinner.findViewById(R.id.tip);
                brSplice=(EditText) brSplice.findViewById(R.id.brSpoj);
                brCon=(EditText) brCon.findViewById(R.id.brKon);
                cLen=(EditText) cLen.findViewById(R.id.duzKabel);
                minPow=(EditText) minPow.findViewById(R.id.minPow);
                recPow=(EditText) recPow.findViewById(R.id.recPow);

                double sFAtt=mValAtts.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmAtt();
                fibLoss = kons.getsLoss()*Double.parseDouble(brSplice.getText().toString())+kons.getcLoss()*Double.parseDouble(brCon.getText().toString())+Double.parseDouble(cLen.getText().toString())*sFAtt+ kons.getsMarg();
                fibLen = (Double.parseDouble(minPow.getText().toString())-Double.parseDouble(recPow.getText().toString())-kons.getsLoss()*Double.parseDouble(brSplice.getText().toString())-kons.getcLoss()*Double.parseDouble(brCon.getText().toString()))/sFAtt;
                lossBud = fibLoss+Double.parseDouble(minPow.getText().toString())-Double.parseDouble(recPow.getText().toString());
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);

                double[] rez=new double[3];
                rez[0]=fibLoss; rez[1]=fibLen;rez[2]=lossBud;

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putDoubleArray("key",rez);

                SecondFragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
                fragment2.setArguments(bundle);


            }
```

logcat:

```
2023-07-15 17:47:46.538 17344-17344/com.example.optickikalkulator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.optickikalkulator, PID: 17344
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double[] android.os.Bundle.getDoubleArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.optickikalkulator.SecondFragment.onCreateView(SecondFragment.java:28)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8252)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
```

I'm guessing I didn't initialize something, I didn't set up the bundle properly or I didn't receive the bundle properly.
Also I'm sorry if my English isn't good or if I didn't explain the problem properly, English is my second language and I'm a really amateur programmer.